# Issue with adding permissions for user roles in Superset using appbuilder

Tags: flask-restful, apache-superset, flask-appbuilder

I'm facing an issue in Superset where the updates made to permissions for a role are not getting reflected in the ab_permission_view_role table in the database. When I add a new permission for a role using the Superset UI, it shows up correctly in the user interface, but the corresponding entry is not being created or updated in the database.

I have checked the ab_permission_view_role table and confirmed that the new permission is not being added. I have also tried manually adding the permission to the role using the SQLAlchemy API, but the changes are still not being persisted in the database.

I have cleared the cache using the superset cache clear command, but it didn't resolve the issue. I also checked the Superset logs, but there are no error messages or warnings related to this problem.

Is there another table or storage mechanism in Superset where these updates are saved? Am I missing any configuration or additional steps that need to be performed to ensure that the changes made to permissions for a role are properly persisted in the ab_permission_view_role table?

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!